# Java daemons launched with multiple -Xmx option (hadoop)

Tags: java, hadoop

On a hadoop clusters that I am using, but do not have admin rights to, I see that the hadoop daemons for JobTracker, TaskTracker and DataNode are launched with the -Xmx options specified twice. Something like

```
/usr/java/default/bin/java -Dproc_datanode -Xmx1000m ... -Xmx128m ...
```

Now, in this case which option takes precedence? Is it the max of the two or the one that comes first or last?

This might not be specific to hadoop, just encountered it in this context so mentioning it.

Comment: Good question... You should report this to the admin. If you want to test by yourself, maybe use `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()`?

Comment: I have, but they are yet to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @fge, I tried it and it seems to be picking up the last option. I'll post a detailed answer once the SO allows me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As suggested by @fge I tested this with a standalone java program, with the following main method

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    long mem = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
    System.out.println("Max mem="+mem/(1024*1024) + "m");       
}
```

and launched it with multiple -Xmx options, it seems to be picking up the **last one**. E.g.

`java -Xmx100m -Xmx20m -Xmx400m`
The program output is 
`Max mem=395m`

Comment: That particular invocation doesn't prove that it isn't selecting max...

Comment: I can confirm that it picks the last value with 
```-Xmx16384m -Xmx16384m -Xmx3072m```
I got Max mem=2731m